# Handlers and Runnable

Tags: android

I read in a document that when we implement `Runnable` we are creating a new thread and post any code to run inside that thread and we use handler to perform UI updates on the uithread.

But in my below example

```
 private class AutoIncrementer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(plusButtonIsPressed){
            incrementValue();
            handler.postDelayed( new AutoIncrementer(), REPEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used `handler.postDelayed()` to update the UI with incremented value
and again on implementing `onLongClickListener()`

```
plusButton.setOnLongClickListener(
        new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                plusButtonIsPressed = true;
                handler.post(new AutoIncrementer());
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
```

I again use `handler.post(new AutoIncrementer())`..... Why do I need to use this when I am updating the UI through `handler.postDelayed()`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runnable` is not a new thread, it is just a piece of code that can be "run".

Your `handler.post` within `onLongClick` is what kicks off the first run of the `AutoIncrementer`. Then within that code it needs to schedule the next check (as `onLongClick` is only called once, and not repeatedly while the button is held down).